# MySQL Union and JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables

```
purchase_order         item
------------------     ------------
id (PK)                id (PK)
deleted                deleted
name                   name
                       purchase_order_id (FK)
```

How do I return a list of ALL items which are linked to a non-deleted, non-null purchase_order, and all purchase_orders which have no items linked to them, either deleted or not.

E.g example tables

purchase_order

```
  id    name         deleted
  ---------------------------
  1     Big Sale     0
  2     Other Sale   1
  3     Empty Sale   0
```

item

```
  id    name         deleted  purchase_order_id
  ----------------------------------------------
  1     Fruit        1        1
  2     Bread        0        1
  3     Water        0        2
```

The correct query gives me this:

```
po_id name          item_id  name
------------------------------------
1      Big Sale     2        Bread
3      Other Sale   NULL     NULL
```

Edit: this is where I've got to but the problem is stipulating that i.deleted = 0, it stops any rows which don't join on an item from returning

```
SELECT po.id, po.name, i.id, i.name
FROM purchase_order po
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.purchase_order_id=po.id
WHERE po.deleted = 0 AND i.deleted = 0
```

Comment: So what have you tried

Comment: Added the query

Comment: Move the `AND...` to just before the `WHERE...`

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't know you could do that in the context of a LEFT JOIN that's brilliant thank you

Answer (score 1):

@strawberry gave me the answer

```
SELECT po.id, po.name, i.id, i.name
FROM purchase_order po
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.purchase_order_id=po.id AND i.deleted = 0
WHERE po.deleted = 0
```

Comment: Sorry about that. :)